# Virtual Machines and SSD's

Tags: windows-7, macos, ssd, vmware-fusion

The general rule of thumb is to host the VM on a separate drive than the host.  Is this necessary with an SSD drive?  I'm looking to get a 120gb SSD for my mbp to run Windows 7 VM's as well as OS X.  Any other tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not necessary per se, anything you can do to put the VM disk I/O on a different channel will make a big imptovement. Especially if the VM uses the disk a great deal. I would suggest a drive in the optical drive bay or a USB 3.0/eSATA external

Comment: It's only an improvement if the host I/O load is already high.  On most current SSDs, this isn't going to be the case, and there's *plenty* of IOPS to spare for a VM (or two, or more) without a significant slowdown in the host.

Answer (score 3):

SSds get their performance from a lot of internal parallelism. But in order to make use of it they need a relatively heavy IO load. On desktops most good SSDs are absolutely starved for IO load. Adding a VM will not hurt performance at all. At least not until you start moving enough data to saturate the SATA connection.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it is a rule of thumb.  Why not run it as you'd like and if performance is an issue, make adjustments.